# Can (endless) CSS keyframe animations be stopped at certain time point or a defined keyframe?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to find out if CSS today offers enough tools to have animations run until an event tells them to stop?

Yes this is possible see snippet, however:

This animation will jump to the end if stopped in between. I was wondering if it can be stopped at any certain point of the computed keyframes. So basically like a wheel of fortune keep spinning the `DIV` until it's stopped and when stopped while upside down remain upside down until maybe restarted?

snippet:

```css
#wrap {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 700ms linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#wrap:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

#mouth {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  top: 52px;
  left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#left-eye {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#right-eye {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 25px;
  right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

@keyframes rotateDiv {
  from {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#wrap {
  animation-duration: 1200ms;
  animation-name: rotateDiv;
  animation-iteration-count: 0;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>
  <div id='left-eye'>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div id='right-eye'>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div id='mouth'>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='start' onClick="document.getElementById('wrap').style.animationIterationCount = 'infinite';">
<input type='button' value='stop' onClick="document.getElementById('wrap').style.animationIterationCount = '0';">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pause and resume CSS animations using `animation-play-state` and toggling a class:

**CSS:**

```
.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
function pause() {
    wrap.classList.add("paused");
}

function play() {
    wrap.classList.remove("paused");
}
```

```css
.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

#wrap {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 700ms linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#wrap:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

#mouth {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  top: 52px;
  left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#left-eye {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#right-eye {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 25px;
  right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  animation-duration: 1200ms;
  animation-name: rotateDiv;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotateDiv {
  from {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id = "wrap" class = "paused">
  <div id = "left-eye">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id = "right-eye">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id = "mouth">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<input type = "button" value = "start" onClick = "play()">
<input type = "button" value = "stop" onClick = "pause()">
```

Comment: Just adding and removing a paused class works really nice. Now I hope someone knows more about part 2 of the question, How to obtain an absolute value from the paused state as a keyframe number or a time offset?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider adjusting the [animation play state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) rather than the iteration count. This will allow you to stop the animation at your desired point, but not reset it to the beginning.

```js
function play() {
  let target = document.getElementById('wrap')
  target.style.animationPlayState = 'running'
  let styles = getComputedStyle(target)
  console.log(styles.getPropertyValue('animation-play-state'))
}

function pause() {
  let target = document.getElementById('wrap')
  target.style.animationPlayState = 'paused'
  let styles = getComputedStyle(target)
  console.log(styles.getPropertyValue('animation-play-state'))
}
```

```css
#wrap {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 700ms linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#wrap:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

#mouth {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  top: 52px;
  left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#left-eye {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#right-eye {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 25px;
  right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  animation-duration: 1200ms;
  animation-name: rotateDiv;
  animation-iteration-count: 0;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes rotateDiv {
  from {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>
  <div id='left-eye'>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div id='right-eye'>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div id='mouth'>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='start' onClick="play()">
<input type='button' value='stop' onClick="pause()">
```

---

#### Edit:

If you want to access information regarding a component's computed styles, you can use the [getComputedStyle function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). This will provide information within Javascript about all of an element's computed styles. The returned value from getComputedStyle can be used with the [getPropertyValue function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) to provide information regarding a specific property.

Comment: that's nice and simple, but how can javascript read the point where it was paused? Is there a way to access a computed state, a keyframe number or animation time offset?

Comment: I added an edit regarding getting information from an elements current CSS state using JS.

Comment: added `window.getComputedStyle(wrap, null).getPropertyValue("transform")` in my second snippet below. This returns a matrix object. But I cannot detect a logic from the paused output to reverse calculate the animation state in either frames or milliseconds. Anyone more experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

This was very useful so far, yet the remaining question related to these answers:

I added `window.getComputedStyle(wrap, null).getPropertyValue("transform")` and write it to an output field. This returns the matrix state of the animation. How should the matrix be interpreted to know at what rotation degree or what keyframe it was paused? I found 4 `float` values in the matrix. Some values seem to be always the same as, or the negative value of one other value. So I guess I can calculate back to milliseconds with these values?

Or maybe there is a different property to read from with `getComputedStyle()` that makes this a bit simpler?

I have moved the snipped to a new more detailed question at: [How can an animation keyframe or time offset be calculated from a CSS transform matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382870/)