# How can an animation keyframe or time offset be calculated from a CSS transform matrix?

Tags: javascript, css

What is the relation of a 4 digit transformation matrix obtained from the paused animation state?

Can we calculate back to milliseconds since the beginning of the loop, or back to the degree of rotation?

Are there other parameters we can get from `getComputedStyle()` that tell us details about the the computed state of an animation?

I am posting this as a new independent question after the first part was answered here: [Can (endless) CSS keyframe animations be stopped at certain time point or a defined keyframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381132/)

```js
function pause() {
    wrap.classList.add("paused");
    state.value = 'paused at: '+window.getComputedStyle(wrap, null).getPropertyValue("transform");
}

function play() {
    state.value = 'running';
    wrap.classList.remove("paused");
}
```

```css
.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

#wrap {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 700ms linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#wrap:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

#mouth {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  top: 52px;
  left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#left-eye {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#right-eye {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 25px;
  right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  animation-duration: 1200ms;
  animation-name: rotateDiv;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotateDiv {
  from {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id = "wrap" class = "paused">
  <div id = "left-eye">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id = "right-eye">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id = "mouth">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<input type = "button" value = "start" onClick = "play()">
<input type = "button" value = "stop" onClick = "pause()"><br><br>
state:<br>
<input type = "text" value = "" id = "state" size="85%">
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are on the wrong track. The animations are managed by the system and it makes them "turn" when it over time. for example, if on the system it has to manage a download it can very well freeze your animation. Which means that there is no guarantee that even the slightest animation or transition, even if it is set to last X milliseconds, the actual elapsed time is almost always different.

Comment: that's why I asked the question. How can we get an absolute value back that tells us either the keyframe(s) CSS has computed up to the point the animation was paused, or the milliseconds since start of an animation loop. Or better the degrees of rotation of the sprite. I am definitely not meaning the elapsed system milliseconds measured from starting the animation.

Comment: new Date(Date.now()) and addEventListener('transitionend',

Comment: think of it like a wheel of fortune, when the animation is paused we should know what is currently on top or what is on the bottom? Or simpler see it as a rolling beach ball with colors, where we can calculate what color is top and what is bottom when randomly stopped.

Comment: Let me classify further. The animation is driven by a `transform` receiving `rotate(360deg)` as a target state to be done after `1200ms`. When reading from `getComputedStyle()` the `transform`returns a matrix, and not a degree value. The question is how to get degree from matrix?

Comment: TL:DR from the duplicate: it's all about Math, this is not a CSS or JS issue, you simply to understand the matrix transformation and it's mathematical meaning